# Is the word "wished" here used for narrative or a hypothetical situation?

Tags: past-tense

> Jenny wished she hadn't been so careless

The answer key says that "wished" here is used for a hypothetical situation, but I fail to see how. Since the word isn't part of a conditional clause, shouldn't  it simply refers to Jenny made this wish in the past?

Comment: She wished that she were in the hypothetical situation of having been more careful about something she had done earlier.

Comment: Wishes are always hypothetical at the time they happen.